# Disable ruby on rails job for test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, delayed-job, rails-activejob

I'm writing controller test with rspec and after action completed, my job supposed to send email to the admin user. But I'd like to disable this job for my tests or mock it somehow. How can I do this?

I'm using [`delayed_job_active_record`](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_active_record) + [`daemons`](https://github.com/thuehlinger/daemons) gems.

```
class AdminNotificationJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(method, parameter)
    User.admin.includes(:profile).each do |admin|
      AdminMailer.send(method, admin, parameter).deliver_later
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
#config/environment/test.rb
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :test

# in spec
expect { your_action_that_triggers_job_enqueuing }
  .to have_enqueued_job(AdminNotificationJob)
  .with(your_arguments)
```

Comment: config.active_job.queue_adapter = :test - this is what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your controller test would look like this:

```
it "enqueues a AdminNotification" do
  expect {
    get :your_controller_action, {}
  }.to have_enqueued_job(AdminNotificationJob)
end
```

This uses the [`#have_enqueued_job`](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/matchers/have-enqueued-job-matcher) method found on [`rspec-rails`](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/matchers/have-enqueued-job-matcher)

Comment: simultaneously :) +1

Comment: I think that's called 'twinning' ? ;)